# Testing functions with arguments in React with Jest Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function named **toggleFilter()** in a react component which looks like this:

```
toggleFilter = (filterType, filterName) => {
        const filterApplied = this.state.appliedFilterList[filterType].includes(filterName);

        if (filterApplied) {
            //Remove the applied filter
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                appliedFilterList: {
                    ...prevState.appliedFilterList,
                    [filterType]: prevState.appliedFilterList[filterType].filter(filter => filter !== filterName)
                }
            }));
        } else {
            //Add the filter
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                appliedFilterList: {
                    ...prevState.appliedFilterList,
                    [filterType]: [...prevState.appliedFilterList[filterType], filterName]
                }
            }));
        }
    };
```

This function is being passed to the child components as :

```
 <ChildComponent  toggleFilter={this.toggleFilter} />
```

So, i am trying to test this toggleFilter() function like this:

```
 it("checks for the function calls", () => {
    const toggleFilterMockFn = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(
        <ProductList
            headerText="Hello World"
            productList={data}
            paginationSize="10"
            accessFilters={["a 1", "a 2"]}
            bandwidthFilters={["b 1", "b 2"]}
            termsFilters={["t 1", "t 2"]}
            appliedFilterList={appliedFilter}
            toggleFilter={toggleFilterMockFn}
        />
    );
    component.find(FilterDropdownContent).prop("toggleFilter")({ target: { value: "someValue" } });
});
```

But I get the error saying :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

What may be causing the issue? Can someone please help me with this.

**EDIT 1:** I tried the below test case:

```
expect(toggleFilterMockFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(appliedFilter, "access");
```

But I get the below error :

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [{"access": ["Access Type Of The Service"], "bandwidth": ["the allowed band width ", "the allowed band width"], "term": ["term associated with the service"]}, "access"]
    But it was not called.
```

Comment: why are you passing `{ target: { value: "someValue" } }` object as function argument? your actual function expects two arguments  `filterType and filterName`, you may need to pass the values for them as  an argument in your test. and your test should be checking whether the mock function is called with argument or not?

Comment: If you are using jest, then you try this API.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-

Comment: @GaleelBhasha , thanks for the response. So you mean to say that instead of `{ target: { value: "someValue" } }` , I have to pass the arguments like (appliedFilterlist, filter) ? Am I correct?

Comment: yes, `{ target: { value: "someValue" } }` is usually used to pass the event object as 2nd argument for the `.simulate()` method.

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md

Comment: Okay.I have tried running the test as you mentioned, but I am still getting an error. Ihave posted my test case and the error message in an edit above.Could you please check once. Also, I have 1 doubt in the above comment that you mentioned. If the function doesnot have any arguments , then `({ target: { value: "someValue" } })` part remains blank or we need not include that part?

Comment: you might need to share the code and full test file to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render a parent and test a child function like that.  Instead, you should render `<FilterDropdownContent />` directly, and then write a test that simulates an event (like click) and checks to see if the function was called.

Something like this for example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<FilterDropdownContent />', () => {
  let wrapper, toggleFilter;
  beforeEach(() => {
    toggleFilter = jest.fn();
    wrapper = shallow(
      <FilterDropdownContent
        toggleFilter={toggleFilter}
      />
    );
  });

  describe('when clicking the .toggle-filter button', () => {
    it('calls `props.toggleFilter()` with the correct data', () => {
      wrapper.find('.toggle-filter').simulate('click');
      expect(toggleFilter).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ target: { value: 'someValue' } });
    });
  }):
});
```

In this example, clicking a link with the `.toggle-filter` class calls the function, but you should be able to adapt this to your specific implementation.